# Taxonomy term description with style, only if the description exists?

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, functions

I am attempting to add a conditional function to my index.php that will return the description of a term in my custom taxonomy on the page for that term above the list of posts only if the description exists. I want it to be in a styled div (id="term-descr"). So I tried:

```
<code>
<div id="term-desc">
<?php echo term_description() ?>
</div>
</code>
```

It worked fine on terms I had the description for, but on all other pages I ended up with the styled outline of the div with nothing in it, which looks funny. I think the function returns a br or something when it returns no value.
So I tried to come up with a conditional function to make this work, something like:

```
<code>
<?php if (term_description() != 0 ) echo {?>
<div id="term-desc">
<?php term_description(); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

which doesn't work. I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do this or if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

`term_description()` returns a string, which might be empty.

So the test should be:

```
$term_desc = term_description();
# debug
print '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars( print_r( $term_desc, TRUE ), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8', FALSE ) . '</pre>';

if ( '' !== $term_desc )
{
    echo "<div id='term-desc'>$term_desc</div>";
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. This worked (I added a ; after the first line) for terms with descriptions, but on pages with out a description I see the outline of the 'term-desc' div. When I look at the source I don't see anything inside the div, but it still gets opened and closed.

Comment: @JPollock Inspect `var_export( $term_desc );` to see what you get here. There is something wrong, maybe a plugin is filtering the value.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how do I inspect a variable? I tried this with all plugins disabled and nothing changed.

Comment: @JPollock I have added a debug line to my example.

Comment: This works perfectly. Weird thing is that it is printing the debug output in the middle of the page above the div that houses the description, which is working fine. I have debugging mode turned off in wp-config.

Comment: I tried replacing the pre tag with my style tags, that gives me two divs, and the first one still prints the p tag.