# Same content shared between multiple posts?

Tags: posts, content

I want to have some cotent shared between various posts.

**Why?**

I am writing a series of posts on backbone js. The thing is every post has some common content ie from where you can download the source code etc. Now everytime I  want to make a new post, I just copy paste that same content. Now one problem is: modifying the content. Today I want to modify the content in all the post. Now I have to manually edit the content in each post.

It will be great if I can use a shared copy something like partial in ruby on rails and just edit that shared copy and all the post having that shared copy get modified.

Any suggestions, plugins etc.

Comment: take a look at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shortcodes-ui/

Comment: Have you tried Post Snippets plugin? You create a snippet, save it as a shortcode, paste that shortcode where you need it, and any future updates you need applied to that content can be handled with ease by simply updating the snippet in question.

Answer (score 1):

Register a [custom taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies), [filter `the_content`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12684/what-params-are-available-with-the-content-filter), and [add the term description](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77683/73).

Comment: Or just add a specific tag to those posts, then filter the_content and add the term description...